# dashing rufus scheduler updating two different values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jira, dashing, rufus-scheduler

I'm using dashing to display some information taken from Jira bug tracking system.

Using the plugin: https://gist.github.com/christiangalsterer/1b24f2b42aa39ba63a92

I have a ruby script that gets the number of Jira issues based on a filter, for each filter in a list. This then gets pushed to 3 number widgets each displaying a different filter.

```
require 'jira'

last_issues = Hash.new(6)

JIRA_FILTERS.each do |filter_data_id, filter|
    SCHEDULER.every '5s', :first_in => 0 do |job|
    last_number_issues = last_issues['filter_data_id']
    client = JIRA::Client.new(JIRA_OPTIONS)
    current_number_issues = client.Issue.jql("filter in (\"#     {filter[:filter]}\")").size
    last_issues['filter_data_id'] = current_number_issues
    send_event(filter_data_id, { current: current_number_issues, last: last_issues['filter_data_id']})
    end
end
```

The problem I have is that I wish to schedule the part that gets the "last_number_issues" every 2 hours, but the rest of it every 10 minutes so I can work out whether the number has gone up or down in that 2 hour time frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could have a "every 2 hours" schedule and a "every 10 minutes" schedule. Or have a single "every 10 minutes" schedule, that, when some timer is over 2h, resets the timer and performs the "every 2h" job.

Comment: I tried two times but couldn't get it working properly

Comment: If you'd like an answer you'd better rework your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up two schedulers in your job like this

```
SCHEDULER.every '10m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  # Your code here
end

SCHEDULER.every '2h', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  # Your code here
end
```

This way you can seperate your logic for "last_number_issues" into its own schedule.

Comment: I did try this, but couldn't get it to work. Because I'm parsing through all of the filters each time, I ended up with all of the last updated values being the same for each filter.